Npm run build error either Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext2(...)' as it is null. or hooks cannot be conditional in Next Js
I am using Next.js with Redux, and I am trying to host the application on Vercel. However, when I attempt to build the app locally, I encounter the following error:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of
'useReduxContext2(...)' as it is null.

If I use if condition then it will be fixed but I am unable to use useEffect like hooks cannot be conditional.
Either any error

Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext2(...)' as it is null.

or

hooks cannot be conditional

I am encountering the following error:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of
'useReduxContext2(...)' as it is null.

This error consistently appears when attempting to build the application locally, and it also occurs during the build step on Vercel. Is there any other solution rather than using if condition?
const STATE = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state)

if (!STATE) {
  return <LoadingPage />
}

const user = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);


Put more logic into the selector, and make sure to only return after all hooks have run.
const user = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state?.auth);
if (!user) return <LoadingPage/> 

note that I changed state.auth to state?.auth, which will return undefined if state is undefined without trying to access .auth.

you know the problem is fixed but i want to add useEffect in the useEffect user variable is given in the dependecy array so if i give any if condition it will throw hooks cannot be conditional error so where do i put the if and useEffect
`const STATE = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state)
if (!STATE) {
return 
}
const user = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
useEffect(() => {
// some operations
}, [user])
`

Again, move the return to the back. Your useEffect has to run every time. You can still do if (user) inside of your useEffect.
